# Returning folder, subfolders and files as a blob c#

Tags: c#, webapi

Iv got a webApi built with Ms.AspNet.webApi on my server i have a Permanent volume with a lot of folders, subfolders and files.

I want to create a method that takes a folder name and returns the folder, subfolders and all files as a blob or any thing else that can be presented in a browser. I have looked all over but i cant find a method that does this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What would a folder with subfolders and files look like when presented in a browser?

Comment: Create a zip file that includes the folder structure and download?  Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Tbh i think the best way would be to the user to start downloading the whole directory and files when he sends in the folder path.

Comment: a zip file would be great yes.

Comment: There is a ZipFile class in System.IO.Compression.  There are also lots of 3rd party libraries for creating zip files.  Give some of those a try.

Comment: Ok thx ill try to find it. Thx a lot.